# Gracefully close an app in Android When HOME or BACK is pressed

Tags: android, forceclose

I have an android app which plays a sound, but when I press HOME/BACK I want the sound to stop and close the app and when the user goes back to the app, I want to start the activity again and not resume.

My onPause() code:

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (pS.isPlaying()) {
        pS.pause(); //stop the sound
        finish();
    }
    else
        finish();
}
```

When the sound is playing and I hit HOME or BACK my app FC and I am posting the Log below:

```
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.testcom.myapp/com.testcom.myapp.MyappActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2354)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2291)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:938)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at com.testcom.myapp.MyappActivity.onPause(MyappActivity.java:119)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3851)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1191)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2341)
04-02 13:06:40.563: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  ... 12 more
```

**Note**: The app closes fine if the sound is playing and HOME/BACK is pressed but if there is no sound playing the app FC when HOME/BACK is pressed. How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (pS!= null && pS.isPlaying()) {
        pS.pause(); //stop the sound
        finish();
    }
    else
        finish();
}
```

I'm guessing that most likely when no sound is playing your `pS` variable is null, and hence you get an NPE when using it.

Comment: WOW... not sure why I didnt realize the pS != null!!! But your code worked like a charm! Thanks Raghav!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to wait for onpause() in activity lifecycle before tat u can finish() your activity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{     

if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME||keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
{
    if (ps!=null) {
    pS.pause(); //stop the sound
    finish();
}
else
  finish();
}
});
```

Comment: Can I add this and the onPause? Or will onPause take care of what you posted here? Thanks.

Comment: no there is a overrided method onkeyDown ,Try rightclick->source->override/implement methods ->select onkeydown() ,this will be automatically invoked when u press home or back button

Comment: So have both Override inside my main Class?

Comment: So take out the onPause and add your code? I am unclear. sorry

Comment: HOME cannot be overrided, it wont catch home press